# numpy array multiplication with arrays of arbitrary dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

I have a numpy array A, which has shape (10,).

I also have, *as of this moment*, a numpy array B with shape (10,3,5).  I want to do a multiplication between these two to get C such that C[0,:,:]=A[0]*B[0,:,:], C[1]=A[1]*B[1,:,:], etc.

I do not want to work this out with loops, one reason being the aesthetics of the thing, the other being that this code needs to be very generic.  I want the user to be able to input pretty much any B of any shape as long as the leading dimension is 10.  For instance, I want the user to be able to also put in a B of shape (10,4).

So: How can I implement this multiplication using numpy?  Thanks.

ADDENDUM:  Have been asked for example.  Will go smaller.  Let's say A is the numpy array [1,2,3] and B is the numpy array [[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]].  I want the multiplication of the two to result in [[1,2],[8,10],[21,24]]. ...

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
>>> #result
>>> c
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 8, 10],
       [21, 24]])
>>>
```

Comment: Please include, *small*, example arrays and the expected output.

Comment: If `B` is `(3,5,10)`, the `A*B` works.  `numpy` automatically adds dimensions at the start as needed (MATLAB adds them at the end).

Comment: As noted above, broadcasting pairs off the right-most dimensions of the arrays. This means that `(A*B.T).T` would match up the length 10s for multiplication and would be a general solution, but I think the `einsum` approach as suggested by DSM is arguably nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `None` (or `np.newaxis`) to expand `A` to match `B`:

```
>>> A = np.arange(10)
>>> B = np.random.random((10,3,5))
>>> C0 = np.array([A[i]*B[i,:,:] for i in range(len(A))])
>>> C1 = A[:,None,None] * B
>>> np.allclose(C0, C1)
True
```

But this will only work for the 2 case.  Borrowing from @ajcr, with enough transposes we can get implicit broadcasting to work for the general case:

```
>>> C3 = (A * B.T).T
>>> np.allclose(C0, C3)
True
```

Alternatively, you could use `einsum` to provide the generality.  In retrospect it's probably overkill here compared with the transpose route, but it's handy when the multiplications are more complicated.

```
>>> C2 = np.einsum('i,i...->i...', A, B)
>>> np.allclose(C0, C2)
True
```

and

```
>>> B = np.random.random((10,4))
>>> D0 = np.array([A[i]*B[i,:] for i in range(len(A))])
>>> D2 = np.einsum('i,i...->i...', A, B)
>>> np.allclose(D0, D2)
True
```

Comment: Whoa, some sophisticated stuff, IMHO!  Actually, your first one works nicely with an edit:  >>> np.array([A[i]*B[i] for i in range(len(A))])  See any problem with that?  Thanks!

Comment: @bob.sacamento: no, that should work-- I was just copying your brute-force example.  But since that creates the array from a slow listcomp, it will be slow for large shapes, and should only be used for testing purposes.

Comment: It's boring and inelegant, but `a[(slice(None),) + (None,) * (b.ndim - 1)] * b` also gets shit done...

Comment: @DSM  Finally got around to trying your einsum method.  I did a direct copy and paste and got the error "ValueError: operand 0 did not have enough dimensions to match the broadcasting, and couldn't be extended because einstein sum subscripts were specified at both the start and end"  Any ideas?  Also, know any good tutorials on einsum.  I find the document page pretty opaque.  Thanks.

Comment: @DSM If you're interested, I also copied and pasted an example from the einsum document -- "np.einsum('...j,j', a, b)" -- and got the same error.  Any idea what this might be about?  Do I have maybe an older version of scipy/numpy that doesn't handle this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Although I like the `einsum` notation, I'll add a little variety to the mix ....

You can add enough extra dimensions to `a` so that it will [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) across `b`.

```
>>> a.shape
(3,)
>>> b.shape
(3,2)
```

`b` has more dimensions than `a`

```
extra_dims = b.ndim - a.ndim
```

Add the extra dimension(s) to `a`

```
new_shape = a.shape + (1,)*extra_dims    # (3,1)
new_a = a.reshape(new_shape)
```

Multiply

```
new_a * b
```

---

As a function:

```
def f(a, b):
    '''Product across the first dimension of b.

    Assumes a is 1-dimensional.
    Raises AssertionError if a.ndim > b.ndim or
     - the first dimensions are different
    '''
    assert a.shape[0] == b.shape[0], 'First dimension is different'
    assert b.ndim >= a.ndim, 'a has more dimensions than b'

    # add extra dimensions so that a will broadcast
    extra_dims = b.ndim - a.ndim
    newshape = a.shape + (1,)*extra_dims
    new_a = a.reshape(newshape)

    return new_a * b
```